# Insert image via PPT Add-In

Tags: image, vba, powerpoint, add-in

I'm programming a PowerPoint Add-In in VBA. I want to have a button to insert the 'default company logo'. The logo is a vector image.

Is it possible to embed the image 'in the add-in itself'? Such that every user who has the add-in, doesn't need the logo file separately as image?

Comment: What I would do in Excel, is placing the image into a Spreadsheet of my `myAddIn.xlam` file and retrieve it from the `Shapes` collection of the workbook. I've never developed in VBA for PPT but I guess you can do the same, i.e. placing the image into a slide of the Add-In file and retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerPoint add-ins contain only code, no slides, graphics or other content, so you can't embed the graphic in the add-in as a graphic.

You could probably add code to the add-in that writes the binary data for the logo graphic out to a file, insert from there, then delete the file (or leave it there for the next use).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, Steve and @Matteo.
So, you're saying that Matteo's  suggestion will not work in PPT, only in Excel?

Comment: Correct.  PPT add-in files have no slides, no masters, nothing but code, so no images.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses! :)

I found a workaround which I like to share.
I converted the picture to an eps-file. Since the eps-file is text-based, I made a VBA-function in my add-in that writes the lines of the eps-image to a temporary text-file called img.eps. Now I can insert the image to my powerpoint slides by the add-in and delete the temporary eps-file.